# Static class-dependant object initialization from child classes

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I have this parent abstract class which defines an Apache logger static object. Something like this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public abstract class A {

    private final static Logger logger;

        (...)

}
```

I know this code is illegal because the logger object is not initialized. The problem is I don't want to initialize it with logger = Logger.getLogger(A.class); because I want each child class to initialize it with its own class object, that way I will know which class caused which errors.

But at the same time I want to include some of my logging methods on the base class A.

What would be the best practice for this? Should I initialize it with A.class, then reinstantiate it for each child class? Somehow that feels incorrect to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize it with the actual class it's created in:

```
logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass()); //log4j way of creating loggers
```

To do this you'll need to remove `static` modifier from your `logger` declaration.
I prefer to keep it `private` and access it via a getter-method, but you can also make it `protected` and access directly from `A` subclasses.

You should not worry that many logger objects will be created, one logger per class instance: under the hood `Logger` contains a map of loggers, and every time you create a new logger - it's being cached. When you try to get logger for the same class the second time - it's just being retrieved from the inner map.

So, if you have 5 classes in your hierarchy - only 5 `Logger` objects will be created, no matter how many times you call `getLogger(getClass())`.

Comment: I can't call getClass from a static scope. That's what my IDE says, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that then. But this applies to this specific case of Apache logger, and I'm curious as to how would one solve this for any other static object. How would you solve it then?

Comment: I would create the same kind factory object (like Logger), and produce new instance of object every time it's called. If for whatever needs (performance/stateless objects/etc) at some point I decide, that I don't want to create new objects any more - I will introduce caching inside the factory-object.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I initialize it with A.class, then reinstantiate it for each
>   child object?

You should reinstantiate it for each child **class**.

Comment: sorry that's what I actually meant.